# Multiple Java Versions

Tags: java

There are few applications which use Java 1.6.2x , few 1.7.1X and other uses 1.7.4X versions.
Since we decided to push all three applications to the user .How to make the applications to use its particular version. There are few web based apps and enterprise apps which requires only a specific set of java versions which is creating issues.

- Os : Win 7
- IE - ver 8

Work around In Progress :
Trying to apply a batch file for each app to set the require java version path , but its not the required solution.

Do we have any generic way which automatically maps to its required java version  , instead of running batch file for each application.

Looking forward your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Although I don't think it's possible, this question is still missing information. What OS is running the application? Is it in a web browser? If so, what web browsers are you using? What have you tried already?

Comment: updated the info , let me know your thoughts

Comment: perhaps you should ask this on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java 1.7.0_40+, you would probably be able to solve your problem by using deployment rule sets:

> A new feature is being introduced in Java 7 update 40 called
>   “Deployment Rule Set,” designed to address the issue of security and
>   compatibility in browser applets without affecting normal back-end
>   Java programs like Eclipse, Freemind, or Tomcat. Specifically this
>   deployment rule set addresses two major points:
>
> The desktop administrator’s ability to control Java version
>   compatibility, and default choices on the end-user’s desktop. For
>   example your users may use most recent security updates for most
>   browser applets but still use an old Java 1.6 for that one legacy
>   application that is no longer maintained. The end-user’s awareness of
>   who created the application and their default interaction (ask, run,
>   or block). By seeing the actual company or signer, the user is
>   protected from running code by someone that they do not know. For
>   example, I would trust “My University” or “Erik Costlow” but not
>   “Unknown publisher” or someone else claiming to be me.

For more information please review Oracle's Article on Deployment Rule Sets

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/introducing_deployment_rule_sets